# Changing background image using the url of a clicked image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, image, background-image

I have a lists of images with the same class. When I click one of the images, I would like jQuery to grab the source of the image and apply it to the body background. Is that possible?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'img.myClass', function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(body).css('background-image', src);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img.myClass").click(function(image){
    $(body).css('background-image', $(image).attr('src'));
});
```